# When I send message from my website's contact form, which is build in Laravel, message is appearing as sent by me

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-mail

Now, I'm building a contact form in Laravel. When I send message via the contact form, I'm taking messages by myself. And that message is appearing in Gmail spam folder.

I'm using my mail service which is connected to my domen. I'm forwarding messages to my gmail account.

My config:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\SendMessage;
use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;

class SendMessageController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            "email" => "required|email",
            "message" => "min:10",
            "subject" => "min:3"
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'company' => $request->company,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message 
        );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('audit@auditors.uz');
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
        });

        Session::flash("success", "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено.");

        return back();
    }
}
```

It is my view:

```
<div>
    <p>{{ $bodyMessage }}</p>
</div>
<p> {{ $email }} tomonidan jo'natildi</p>
```

If somebody knows, why it is happening. Please, help me, I'm going crazy right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with Laravel, this is because you are trying to send an email via your email server from a completely different user and domain. This would get it flagged up pretty easily. Basically, it looks like you are trying to spoof emails if website1.com is sending an email from user1@hotmail.com. It is not a genuine email from the server.

I would recommend using a generic email address on your server to send from, e.g. contact@mysite.com and include the user's email address in the reply-to field.